# Jmeter failed to parse some cookie

Tags: cookies, jmeter, httpclient

I'm getting following error while executing test via Jmeter:

```
WARN  - jmeter.protocol.http.control.HC3CookieHandler: cust_tracking=; path=/; expires=Mon, 01 Dec 2025 00:00:00 ; domain=coral.co.ukUnable to parse expiration date parameter: Mon
```

This seems because of bad Date format (**Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT;** - processed successfully). But anyway, cookie does not set via Cookie Manger and this affects all future requests. I've tried both HC3 and HC4 implementations with different Cookie Policy but this didn't solve the issue.

Is it possible to handle this issue somehow? Maybe there is a way of how to add some custom Date format for CookieHandler; Or maybe it's possible to skip expiration check; Or maybe some other solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use beanshell preprocessor to parse the cookie and send it to further requests. Use cookieManager class to do the same.